# Cannot bind to address after socket program crashes

Tags: python, sockets

If my program crashes before a socket is closed, the next time I run in, I get an error that looks like this;

```
socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

Changing the port fixes the problem.

Is there any way to avoid this, and why does this happen (when the program exits, shouldn't the socket be garbage collected, and closed)?

Comment: If you had run `netstat -an`, you would have seen that your listening port still existed in state `TIME_WAIT`.  Just a tip, I hope that helps in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll take a look at it next time

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` on your listening socket.

A search for those terms will net you many explanations for why this is necessary.  Basically, after your first program closes down, the OS keeps the previous listening socket around in a shutdown state for `TIME_WAIT` time.  `SO_REUSEADDR` says that you want to use the same listening port regardless.

Comment: Thanx, great answer! For those who run in SOL_SOCKET is undefined. 
 use .setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

Answer (score 3):

Most OSes take up to *2* minutes to close the socket when the program doesn't properly close it first. I've hit this many times with C programs that SEGFAULT (and I don't have it handled) or similar.

Edit:
Thanks to [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient) for pointing out [RFC 793 (TCP)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) which defines this timeout.

Comment: RFC 793 (TCP) says that `TIME_WAIT` should be 2MSL, which defaults to 2 minutes, unless further FIN packets are received.  5 minutes would be unusually long.

Answer (score 2):

Other people who are getting this error may be getting it because the port is in use by another process. So check if the port is being used by any other processes and either run your program in another port or kill the blocking processes.