# SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer - Cannot bind to address after program restart

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tcpserver

As a follow-up to [cannot-bind-to-address-after-socket-program-crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270343/cannot-bind-to-address-after-socket-program-crashes), I was receiving this error after my program was restarted:

> socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

In this particular case, instead of using a socket directly, the program is starting its own threaded TCP server:

```
httpd = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('localhost', port), CustomHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

How can I fix this error message?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this particular case, `.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` may be called from the TCPServer class when the `allow_reuse_address` option is set. So I was able to solve it as follows:

```
httpd = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('localhost', port), CustomHandler, False) # Do not automatically bind
httpd.allow_reuse_address = True # Prevent 'cannot bind to address' errors on restart
httpd.server_bind()     # Manually bind, to support allow_reuse_address
httpd.server_activate() # (see above comment)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Anyway, thought this might be useful. The solution will differ slightly in Python 3.0

Answer (score 20):

The above solution didn't work for me but this one did:

```
   SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
   server = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(("localhost", port), CustomHandler)
   server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Interesting, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: same here, this works but not one with httpd.server_bind()
Python 2.6.5

Comment: Worked for me on Python 3.4.3, but Justin's answer did not.

Comment: [According to the documentation this is not recommended, recommended method is to subclass.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.BaseServer.allow_reuse_address)