# How to release reserved resources (e.g. port) in python immediately?

Tags: python, sockets

I am writing a code to transfer a large file over the internet. Therefore, I have to open a socket over a specific port (port = 45678) for sending the data. However, it takes a while that the operating system (Ubuntu 14.04) release that specific port (45678) after the program termination.

I want to run my code for multiple times to use that specific port without waiting for the OS to release the port. **Is there any way that python forces the OS to release the port?**

In addition, all sockets are closed at the end of the file transmission.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/307624/how-to-close-or-unbind-a-port-left-open-by-a-rogue-application

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close a socket left open by a killed program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875177/how-to-close-a-socket-left-open-by-a-killed-program)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use socket in Python as a context manager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772465/how-to-use-socket-in-python-as-a-context-manager)

Comment: @thebjorn I tried "netstat" to find the process to kill it, But no process is shown using port 45678. I also tried "sudo pkill python", but it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your socket is stuck in TIME_WAIT state. Try SO_REUSEADDR call from this question:

[Python: Binding Socket: "Address already in use"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380057/python-binding-socket-address-already-in-use)