# When should I set the allow_reuse_address property in a SocketServer subclass?

Tags: python, socketserver

I've the following subclass of `SocketServer.TCPServer`:

```
class MP3Server (SocketServer.TCPServer):

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, SoundObj, DocRoot):
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self,
                                        server_address,
                                        RequestHandlerClass)
```

Before initializing I'm setting `self.allow_reuse_address` to `True`. But, still, when I stop and restart my server, I get the error about the address which is already in use.

I've also tried to change that line into `SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True`, but it doesn't work the same (and to be honest I didn't expect different with this second solution).

Comment: Try the two solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274320 ?

Comment: @ArminRigo, I've seen them, but in there they are using the class as it is and they are not sub-classing it. I would like to create a subclass which has, by default, that parameter set.

Comment: First call the base class, then set the property. Most probably your `allow_reuse_address` is overwritten by the call to the SocketServer.TCPServer constructor.

Comment: @mguijarr, unfortunately not! That was my first guess and my first try. Nothing changes.